# How to send a PDF file by internet?

Tags: java, jms, rmi, billing

In my telecom billing system in Java, i need to send generated bills(PDF FILES) to another colleague in charge of saving them in a DFS(distributed file system).
The FTP protocole is obsolete.
Can i do that with JMS or RMI? the constraint is that i should not lose time in transferring them.

I have to send Thousands of files.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a P2P connection?

Comment: No i dont have a P2P connection, but it seems interesting. i'll implement it.

Comment: If you already have the generated pdf and if you want to automate the saving in a different location then JMS sounds a better option.

Comment: I add that i have thousands of files.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use http with content type=application/pdf ?

Comment: he doesnt want to download the file, he wants to send it.

Answer (score 0):

How about SCP/SFTP. It's secure, supports compression and provides bulk transfer.